# Camel Choice by Example

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

I have 2 POJOs:

```
public class Witch {
    private Broom broom;
    private List<Spell> spells;

    // constructors, getters/setters, etc.
}

public class ValidatedWitches {
    private List<Witch> goodWitches
    private List<Witch> badWitches;

    // constructors, getters/setters, etc.
}
```

I have a Camel processor I wrote that will produce a `ValidatedWitches` instance (which again, consists of 2 `List<Witch>`):

```
public class WitchValidator implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        List<Witch> witchesToValidate = (List<Witch>)exchange.getIn().getBody();

        ValidatedWitches validated = validate(witchesToValidate);

        exchange.getOut().setBody(validated);
    }

    private ValidatedWitches validate(List<Witch> toValidate) {
        // For each witch, determines if it is a good witch, or a bad witch,
        // and places it on an appropriate list.
        List<Witch> good = new ArrayList<Witch>();
        List<Witch> bad = new ArrayList<Witch>();

        // etc...

        return new ValidatedWitches(good, bad);
    }
}
```

I now want to **route** my list of good witches 1 way, and my list of bad witches another way:

```
<route id="witch-route">
    <!-- Everything before my WitchValidator component... -->

    <to uri="bean:witchValidator?method=process" />

    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>???</simple>
            <to uri="direct:goodWitches" />
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>???</simple>
            <to uri="direct:badWitches" />
        </when>
    </choice>
</route>
```

What can I put inside my `<choice>` to take the `ValidatedWitches.getGoodWitches()` and route them to `direct:goodWitches`, and to take the `ValidatedWitches.getBadWitches()` and route them to `direct:badWitches`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `<choice`> is either one or the other, so in your example you can only reach one destination URI. Therefore you may need to add a `<split>` before the `<choice>` so that you have two separate messages being evaluated.

See [splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) for your options there, for example you may want to create your own POJO with a method that returns a list of two ValidatedWitches objects - one with the "goodWitches" collection populated only and one with the "badWitches" collection populated only.

There are many [predicate](http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html) options available, but an easy one would be to check if each array was empty.

Then your route could look something like this:

```
<to uri="bean:witchValidator?method=process" />
<split>
    <method beanType="SPLITTER_CLASS_NAME" method="SPLITTER_METHOD" />
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body.goodWitches.size} > 0</simple>
            <to uri="direct:goodWitches" />
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${body.badWitches.size} > 0</simple>
            <to uri="direct:badWitches" />
        </when>
    </choice>
</split>
```

Key points:

- Splitter should return a collection of two or more objects
- Choice needs to be able to distinguish between the split objects